# Color dataframe rows by condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to color rows in my DataFrame, according to the condition depending on some column. For example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B":[5,3,2,1,4]})

def color(score):
    return f"background-color:" + (" #ffff00;" if score < 4 else "#ff0000") 

test.style.applymap(color, subset = ["A"])
```

But in this way I get color only at `A` column:

[image: single column color]

Also i can code like this:

```
def color1(score):
    return f"background-color: #ffff00;" 
def color2(score):
    return f"background-color: #ff0000;" 

temp = test.style.applymap(color1, subset = (test[test["A"]< 4].index, slice(None)))
temp.applymap(color2, subset = (test[test["A"] >= 4].index, slice(None)))
```

In this way color will be  ok, but i struggle multiple calls of `applymap` functions. Is there any way to fulfill my goal without the multiple calls?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, by the `subset='A'` you are telling to apply only to column A. If you remove that it will apply to the entire dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B":[5,3,2,1,4]})

def color(score):
    return f"background-color:" + (" #ffff00;" if score < 4 else "#ff0000") 

test.style.applymap(color)
```

[image: ex1]

If you want to apply different formatting in different columns you can easily design something handling one column at a time.

```py
def color2(score):
    return f"background-color: #80FFff;" if score < 4 else None 
test.style.applymap(color, subset='A') \
          .applymap(color2, subset='B')
```

[image: ex2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i mean that if in some rows "A" column value lower than 4 then the **whole** row ("B" colum too) becomes red. Start code from my second example to see correct result.

Comment: @Dranikf - check another answer.

Comment: My hope is that from this you understand how to fix your example. But I edited the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If some complicated mask or set styles is possible create DataFrame of styles and pass to [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with `axis=None`:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = f"background-color: #ffff00;" 
    c2 = f"background-color: #ff0000;" 
    
    m = x["A"]< 4
    # DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    # set columns by condition
    df1.loc[m, :] = c1
    df1.loc[~m, :] = c2

    #for check DataFrame of styles
    print (df1)
    return df1


test.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't understand - the `test.style` is an object, it isn't callable. I suppose you mean to use `test.style.applymap`, but anyway when i set `axis=None` it doesn't call `highlight` at all. To check paste some print in it - it will not be printed.

Comment: @Dranikf - Correct solution is use `test.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)`, there was typo.